# 2.4GHz sender cause 433MHz receiver jammed, vice versa

Tags: rf, wireless, radio

I have a 433MHz receiver placed near a 2.4GHz sender, and they have about a 20cm gap. When 2.4G is actively sending, the 433M receiver can't hear anything from the 433M sender (433M receiver been jammed by 2.4G sender) and vice versa.

Can I put an RF filter on receivers to solve this problem? (High pass for 2.4G receiver, low pass for 433M receiver) Will that work well?

Or should I just use another frequency/RF module and avoid 2.4G or 433M? Maybe 5.8G + 433M or something else?

Both 2.4G and 433M module looks like this one:

[image: RF module]

The power source is independent.

Path: 36V power bus >> 36-to-5.5 DC-DC >> 100uF cap >> RF module; every RF module has a independent 36-to-5.5 DC-DC module and 100uF cap.

The RF module I use only costs about $5, so I'm not sure if it has a solid shielder and filter. (a typical RC filter cost > $50)

Here is also a report about A-Rx being overwhelmed by B-Tx, see (https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2214261-Interference-with-UHF-433-and-video-2-4GHz-Why)

Comment: Given than you are using commercial RF transceiver modules for this task, It's unlikely it's caused by RF inference. Do you power 2.4GHz Transmitter and 433MHz receiver from same power source? If your power source isn't capable of powering both, this could happen. Also if you can buy a 20$ SDR dongle, you can verify if there is any interference on 433MHz when 2.4GHz TX is active.

Comment: @Anuradha The power source is independent. Path: 36V power bus >> 36-to-5.5 DC-DC >> 100uF cap >> RF module; every RF module has a independent 36-to-5.5 DC-DC module and 100uF cap. The RF module I use only costs about $5, so I'm not sure if it has a solid shielder and filter. (a typical RC filter cost > $50) Here is also a report about 433M-Rx being overwhelmed by 2.4G-Tx, see (https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2214261-Interference-with-UHF-433-and-video-2-4GHz-Why)

Comment: Just move antennas to a ~ "lambda/4" distance (or multiple ?) ... if possible?

Comment: @Antonio51 What's your mean by "lambda"? I didn't find such data on the RF module datasheet. The current distance between the two modules is 20cm, the max available distance will be about 40cm. Due to those modules being placed on a controller box, so the max distance will be limited by the size of the controller.

Comment: @Anuradha "Commercial" doesn't necessarily mean high quality, it all depends on how those modules are designed and what circuits they are using internally. It's for example unlikely that such modules use SAW band pass filters in order to shave down costs. $5 modules means it's some manner of shaved Aliexpress design.

Comment: @BrainsOverFlow Lambda in the context of antennas refers to the wavelength of the specific frequency. Rather than trial & error with wavelengths though, you could mount the 433MHz antenna at a 90 degrees angle from the 2.4GHz one, to have less interference between them. Anyway I suspect that the root problem here is the modules. I evaluated the Semtech 433MHz LoRA parts used by these at some point and they were quite prone to disturbances and wouldn't work reliably if you need real-time communication. Narrowband 433MHz transmitters popping up in the spectrum would easily jam them.

Comment: @Lundin That I already know. Yet those are heaps better preventing interference than something put together with discrete components.

Comment: The electromagnetic "field" varies with distance. And so there is "arguably" a distance between the two antennas which should lead to minimal "influence". This is what radio amateurs often do when they have several antennas at different frequencies. The only advantage for them is that the frequency bands are "multiples" of a base frequency. ... so that the "harmonics" of a transmitter fall into the higher frequency bands ... also used by radio amateurs ... And therefore, do not bother anyone else! :-)

Comment: If one owns a "spectrum analyzer", one can "found" a position where a "low dip" is present. At 1/4 "wavelength" multiple (lambda = 1 wavelength) ...

Comment: @Lundin From your experience, I'd better get a bandpass filter for every receiver. For the module, it does come from Aliexpress. There are also some DTU radio modems available, but those are generally too big compared with nrf24 based stuff. Those cost about $30-50, but I don't think those could have a better bandpass filter or narrow band antenna.

Comment: Remember what happens when you travel in a car (very slowly) while listening to FM radio.

Comment: @BrainsOverFlow You get what you pay for. A good on-chip radio IC is some $2-3, then possibly a MCU is required too, another $1, PCB $1-2, screen $1, SMA $1-2, passives $1-2, VCO §1 (ideally TCXO, costs more) and so on... I'm just pulling these numbers out of a hat, but you can see that they don't quite add up. And this would be volume pricing of 1k pcs or so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called **Blocking**. It's part of a continuum whereby a receiver is very sensitive to interference on-channel, less sensitive in the adjacent channel, and progressively less sensitive to other bands and frequencies further away, where filtering in the module is more able to reject interfering signals.

All radio receivers suffer from it, all transmitters can cause it, but to a degree depending on the quality of the RF filtering, and the general build of the module. A transmitter may generate +20dBm, and a receiver be sensitive to -100dBm on channel. That's a colossal ratio, 12 decades of power, for filtering to have to get right.

Commercial modules are built down to a price, and only up to some nominal specification. Whether that specification is capable of handling only a 20 cm distance between modules is another matter. If you've spent $5 a module, then you're unlikely to have bought any serious filtering at that price.

There are many places a receiver could be picking up problems. The most obvious is the antenna, but almost any competent module will have some sort of hardware filter on the way in. It could also be affected by RF signals, which is why the metal box round the module, and through the power supply or control wires if they're not well filtered, especially if the wires connecting to them become resonant at any transmitter frequencies. Tidying up the control and power wires, possibly with ferrite beads, may be part of the solution.

Low cost transmitters will often radiate excessive power at harmonics of the intended RF frequency.

At this price point, and without proper test gear, you just have to experiment. The first thing to test is distance, now that you have the devices operating from different power supplies. Get a handle on the size and repeatability of the problem, by moving them apart until they work. Are you nearly there, or do you need metres or more?

Ideally, get some more modules, of the same or indeed different make, at least one more of each. Is the behaviour repeatable across modules? A receiver may be sensitive to some other frequency, or a transmitter cause interference, simply because they are faulty, and that fault need not stop them working on their intended frequency. You might find one brand of module that works much better. This would be both a blessing and a curse - would you be able to find that exact make again or would it be being built as well if you needed a repeat build?

The modules appear to have external antennae. You may get a result moving the antennae apart, or orienting them differently. Are the antennae designed for the specific bands you're using? The first filter the RF sees is the frequency response of the antenna. If moving the antennae apart gives a solid improvement, then RF filter or more narrowband antennae would be likely to give you a solution.

Comment: English isn't my native so, to sum up:

1. A filter could solve the blocking issue.
2. A narrow band antenna could solve the issue.
3. Choose only one from 1&2 will be enough.
4. An extra shielder will help to solve the issue.
5. Give a more significant gap for two modules and point in different directions.
6. Try different hardware manufacturer combinations, low cost but low efficiency and could fail.

Please let me know if I lost any key points.

I'll take the 3, 4, 5 approaches.

Comment: @BrainsOverFlow not really, anything might be the problem. Get your setup repeatable first, then try distance to find out how bad the problem is, only then try trial solutions.

Comment: Test first, then apply the solution. Got it, thanks!